# Hyperlink on table not working in JasperReports Server 4.7.0

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've installed JasperReports Server 4.7.0 and have designed a report with table and the table 
contain two fields, one of the field contain hyperlink.

The report run perfectly but when I click the hyperlink field the formatting hide column option will come unable to open the hyperlink report. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is delete the column headers from the table component and add a Column header band there you can add the columns for the table fields then add hyperlink.